# UNKNOWN NAME Showing up instead of actual phone number

Tags: iphone, call, caller-id

When receiving a phone call from a number not listed in my Contacts, the name displays as "UNKNOWN NAME" rather than simply showing the number initiating the call. I'm pretty sure this hasn't always been the case, and that my phone used to list the number itself.

Is there any way to get it to go back to listing the number? There seems to be no option for this under Settings.

Answer (score 1):

The cell phone carrier sends this information, so I would do in order:

- check for carrier setting update
- Check for iOS update
- Test with a couple numbers (delete the number from contacts if needed)
- If it’s systematic, restart the device and update it.
- If it’s not systematic, call your carrier for support.

In the end, carrier support may be needed to validate why this happens if it’s not a simple need to update or restart and retest.